# Two different managedObjects and one sqlite database?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sqlite, core-data

I am trying to create two tables within the same sqlite database. Now, this two managedObjectModels don't run in the same instance. Let me explain...I run the application once, and I create the managedObject in the persistent store, programmatically. Let say I have 5 attributes for that one. Then I run it again and I create a new managedObject in the persistent store, but this time I only use 3 attributes...how can I make this possible? Right now it crashes because the amount of attributes don't match.

Regards and thanks!

Comment: I'm very confused by your description of your problem.  Are you using Core Data in this app?  Are you adding new entities to your data model? Is there any code you could show that might make it more clear what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am using Core Data yes. I create the managedObjectModel programmatically though instead of using an xcdatamodel. The managedObjectModel creates X amount of attributes depending on how much X is (lets just say that X is gathered from somewhere else, so it is not always the same). Therefore if I run the application once and X=5, the managedObjectModel will create 5 attributes (called attribute1...etc). Then if I run it again and X=3, then the managedObjectModel will create 3 attributes. Now since I am using only one SQLite database, it crashes when the attribute amount is not the same.

Comment: The error I get is: 'This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores.  It cannot perform a save operation.' I am pretty sure it is because of the attributes amount conflict though... because if I set X to a constant amount, I don't get the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer is to not create your data model programmatically.  It should be created at design-time and not modified.  Instead, you should design your data model to be flexible enough to meet your needs.  For instance, instead of creating one entity with a variable number of attributes, create two entities, one with a one-to-many relationship to the other, and store what information would have gone in your variable number of attributes there.

Comment: hmm that seems like a plausible solution. Ok, lets say I create a relationship called "attributes" to another model. How do I access attribute1...attribute2 and such? And what does this other model should include exactly?

Comment: I would start here http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html . And to be clear, you're creating a new entity, not a new model.  Your relationship would be one of the attributes on your first entity and would return an NSSet of objects of the type of your second entity.  What information it contains is up to you entirely.

Comment: So basically if I ask for [entity valueForKey:@"attributes"] it would return an NSSet of values? 

And yeah sorry, I have been doing it programmatically so many times now that I forgot that they are called entities.

Comment: I've generally used concrete NSManagedObject subclasses to represent entities, but using valueForKey will also work.  You'll get an NSSet of NSManagedObjects with an entity type of the second entity you create to hold your attribute data.  That is, assuming you have previously added some objects to that relationship.

Comment: I really don't know how to deal with xcdatamodel relationships. I have tried looking for good tutorials out there... but there aren't really any, not that I have found anyway. Are you sure there is no other way though?

Comment: This http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started is a good place to start to learn about relationships in Core Data.

Comment: THanks for your help Paul. It did help, I had to figure out a few stuff playing around, but it definitely helped. Cheers!